# asp.net export to Excel UTF-8

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Here is my code :

```
 var model = _db.FacebookInfo.OrderByDescending(f => f.Followers).ToList();
    var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();



    grid.DataSource = (from u in model
                       select new
                       {
                           fullname = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(u.FullName, "<span .*?>(.*?)", ""),
                           followers = u.Followers,
                           friends = u.Friends,
                           url = u.FbLink
                       }).ToList();

    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Nana bregvadze Friends.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.End();
```

It just create an excel file, but i have an unicode problem, can't read Georgian charachters. Look at the picture :

[image]

Maybe it's a duplicate but no solution worked for me.

Comment: There's no problem with Excel and UTF8. Your code simply doesn't generate Excel at all - it creates an HTML table with a fake header and file extension that Excel *imports* as HTML. Use a library like EPPlus to create *real* XLSX files. It's actually easier, a call like ` ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(model) will generate a Sheet from any IEnumerable collection

Comment: Just there is no way  to read utf-8 charachtares from html?

Comment: Of course there is, provided you set the proper HTTP headers. But why insist with the ugly hack when the correct solution is easier? What happens when you find the *next* issue when importing HTML files with default settings in Excel? What happens if any firewall or proxy between you and the client detects that instead of a binary `xls` file you sent an HTML file and blocks it? What if the client wants formatting? Child's play with a real Excel file, really hard with HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't create a real XLSX file, it creates an HTML table with a faked header and extension. Excel will *import* this file using the end user's default settings and locale.

Instead of faking Excel files, you can easily create a real XLSX file with minimal code using a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). There's even a [Web Application](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) example in the Codeplex site. You can use `LoadFromCollection` instead of `LoadFromDataTable` in your case:

```
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Create the worksheet
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
    //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1.
    // Print the   column names on row 1
    var table=ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(model, true);


    //Write it back to the client
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Note that `table` is an actual ExcelRange object, that can be given a name, style etc.

Answer (score -1):

Okey i solve the problem :
just change Response.ClearContent() to Response.Clear() and add

```
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />")
```

full code :

```
 var model = _db.FacebookInfo.OrderByDescending(f => f.Followers).ToList();
        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView(); 
    grid.DataSource = (from u in model
                       select new
                       {
                           fullname = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(u.FullName, "<span .*?>(.*?)", ""),
                           followers = u.Followers,
                           friends = u.Friends,
                           url = u.FbLink
                       }).ToList();

    grid.DataBind();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Nana bregvadze Friends.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.End();
```